# Avoid dynamic linking in dependencies

Tags: rust

I am developing a project against a custom linux and I am having troubles with dynamic dlls that are referenced by dependencies.

Is there a way to know if a dependency has dynamic linked libraries before hand? Is it possible to somehow avoid those libraries? I want to have a static binary (MUSL didn’t work for me as one dependency doesn’t compile with it).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're compiling against glibc, you'll need to have at least some dynamic linking.  While it is possible to statically link glibc, that isn't a supported configuration since the name service switch won't work in such a case.

In general, you should expect a build-dependency on `cc` or `pkg-config` to be an indicator of the use of a C or C++ library.  That isn't a guarantee either way, but it is probably going to be the case the vast majority of the time.  Some of those libraries will be able to be linked statically, but of course if you do that you must recompile your code every time any of your dependencies has a security update or you'll have a vulnerability.  There's unfortunately no clear way to tell whether static linking is an option in such a case other than looking at the `build.rs` or the documentation of the crate.